# echo shows up in the form

Tags: php, join

I have made a `join.php` file and everything works but when I click on register the forms have echo printed inside.

I dont know what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>iStore</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="head">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="current" href="index.html" title="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="join_form.html" title="">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="join.php" title="">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="area"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="content_left">
      <h1> Please Register Below </h1>

      <form name="form1" method="post" action="register.php">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr> 
      <td width="24%" align="left" valign="top">First Name</td>
      <td width="76%"><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name2" value="<? echo $first_name; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="left" valign="top">Last Name</td>
      <td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<? echo $last_name; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="left" valign="top">Email Address</td>
      <td><input name="email_address" type="text" id="email_address" value="<? echo $email_address; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="left" valign="top">Desired Username</td>
      <td><input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo $username; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="left" valign="top">Information about you:</td>
      <td><textarea name="info" id="info"><? echo $info; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Join Now!"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

      </div>
      <div id="content_right">
      <h4>Latest Work</h4>
      <div class="item_box">
      <img src="images/t1.jpg" width="200" height="70" border="0" alt="Dragon" title="Dragon" /><br />
      <strong>Dragon</strong> </div>
      <div class="item_box">
      <img src="images/t2.jpg" width="200" height="70" border="0" alt="Bricks" title="Bricks" /><br />
      <strong>Bricks </strong></div>
      </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
<div id="footer"></div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your values being set?

Answer (score 6):

either change `<?` to `<?php`

or set `short_open_tag` to `on` in `php.ini`/`.htaccess`

Also, I hope you have all these values passed through `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Hi col. I have tried to do before "<?php"  it doesnt work at all. I am new to php so i dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @jollyton what is the name of the file with the code you posted here?

Answer (score 0):

either you need to use `<?php` or actually install/start php and apache

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<? echo 'test'; ?>` and you see only the "test", then the setting ***short_open_tag*** in your php.ini is set to ***off***. If possible set it to ***on*** or use `<?php echo 'test'; ?>`

When you can use the short tags you can use also `<?='test'?>` . ***"="*** is like echo in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP error will occur because the variable $username is not set at the first instance.
What you need to do is to perform a check as in the following example

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if (isset ($username)) { echo $username;} ?>">
```